# How to find ios phone users that are within 1 mile of me - without polling every user?

Tags: android, ios, location, polling

We are working on an app with the following requirements:

- Users will have a Friends list (small subset of users)
- User will need to know when a 'Friend' is close to them (aprox < 1 mile)

We are currently doing the following:

- **Each User posts there location to a central DB every 15 mins**
- User searches DB for Users that are friends & distance < 1 mile

The issue is - **thats alot of Location Polling** & many users don't like constant polling.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The current approach looks perfect here.

Other wise you need to manually trigger user that he/she needs to update their current location.

What you can do if some one wants to know near by friends list:

1. Make a web service call that user from X group is trigger an event for location updates.
2. Send a push notification to all other user from group X that update current location / sync current location with online database.
3. Filter users from latest current location details.

Pros:

- You will get real time location updates (fraction of mins)
- Only limited users (group of users) needs to update their location
- Do not need to constantly location polling

Cons:

- Push notification required
- User have to manually sync their location, if some one does not sync it will be not effective.

However there are many things which needs to be consider for scenario above, I have roughy listed which strikes in a mind first.

Again it still depends on application architecture and server configuration to manage every alternatives.

Comment: Hi H - I see. So Push Notify the SubSet ('Friends' ) which could active say a higher rate of polling to a smaller group for even a limited set of time (6 hrs). That could work well for us. Fine Grained Approach. Thanks for great info

Answer (score 1):

"User searches DB for Users that are friends & distance < 1 mile"
Maybe it will be better to server side make that job?
The clients only  ask server - 'Any friends around me?' 
Also you can try to deliver that info by push notifications. But notification can arrive with delay (or may not delivered at all).

Comment: check the question he said he wants " without polling every user?" and the process which u said  will need polling to get latest location and data

Comment: Hi D - yeah - the push to start polling a subset is now what we're thinking of - thx for info!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Android but for iOS you can configure your app to update location more conservatively using **significant-change** location as referred to in the [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html). Then when your user is actively using the app (or some other business logic such as close to an active friend) temporarily change to the **standard location** service for greater accuracy and more frequent polling.

By using the significant change method you could just update the server occasionally rather than every 15 minutes and sometimes more frequently if a person is on the move and then alter your search predicate to reflect these update changes.

The part that seemed most relevant was:

> The **significant-change** location service delivers updates only when there has been a significant change in the device’s location, such as 500 meters or more.

Comment: Hi D - wow - great to know. Yes- it looks like we will use the 'ask everyone' ...but use every flag available to limit the 'everyone' set. significant-change - looks like one of those USEFULL events we can leverage - thanks so much for info

Comment: Looks like Android has similar: 

public void requestLocationUpdates (long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)

Added in API level 9
Register for location updates using a Criteria and pending intent.